# Constantly updating RecyclerView items

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

I have a RecyclerView which contains some items. Each item displays an event and it will have a text view representing the difference in time between the current time and the event time. I want to constantly update the items every second or minute (just need to rebind the item to the view holder). I am using the following code but it does not update all the items (just some of them and the updated items even flash which do not look good).

```
LinearLayoutManager layoutManager = (LinearLayoutManager) mRecyclerView.getLayoutManager();
int firstVisibleItem = layoutManager.findFirstVisibleItemPosition();
int lastVisibleItem = layoutManager.findLastVisibleItemPosition();
Log.d(TAG, "Updating clock: " + firstVisibleItem + ", " + lastVisibleItem);
if (firstVisibleItem > 0 && lastVisibleItem > 0) {
      for (int i = firstVisibleItem; i <= lastVisibleItem; i++) {
          mAgendaAdapter.notifyItemChanged(i);
}
```

Is there any workaround for this problem?

Comment: Well, this post is old but recently I faced a similar problem and came up with a solution. Solution is that make each item view to have its own lifecycle and viewmodel. I was looking for a usecase to my story at medium ( https://medium.com/@itguru4all/lifecycle-aware-viewholder-7074a9a0049e). I found this question a perfect match.

Answer (score 2):

the flash you see is the default animation for the item change.
you should be able to disable it with something like -

```
recyclerView.getItemAnimator().setSupportsChangeAnimations(false);
```

if you want all items to update can you just call

```
mAgendaAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged()
```

Comment: I tried notifyDataSetChanged() but the relative time does not change for some items

Comment: i think we won't be able to help from just the code provided.

Answer (score 1):

Here you just notify the visible items but we need to notify all.
Just update the List which is used in the *Adapter* to bind data.

```
mAgendaAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged()
```

Or you can track the changed items and loop through them and call

```
mAgendaAdapter.notifyItemChanged(i);
```

Comment: The problem is even some visible items are not updated.